# Error in saving entity by extending reactive repository in SpringBoot with webflux

Tags: spring-boot, reactive

1. Here is my document POJO

   @Document(collection = "users")
   public class Employee implements Serializable {

   ```
   @Id
   private UUID id;

   private String firstName;

   private String lastName;

   private String email;


   public UUID getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public void setId(UUID id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
       return firstName;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
       this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
       return lastName;
   }

   public void setLastName(String lastName) {
       this.lastName = lastName;
   }

   public String getEmail() {
       return email;
   }

   public void setEmail(String email) {
       this.email = email;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) return true;
       if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;

       Employee employee = (Employee) o;

       if (!getId().equals(employee.getId())) return false;
       if (getFirstName() != null ? !getFirstName().equals(employee.getFirstName()) : employee.getFirstName() != null)
           return false;
       if (getLastName() != null ? !getLastName().equals(employee.getLastName()) : employee.getLastName() != null)
           return false;
       return getEmail().equals(employee.getEmail());
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       int result = getId().hashCode();
       result = 31 * result + (getFirstName() != null ? getFirstName().hashCode() : 0);
       result = 31 * result + (getLastName() != null ? getLastName().hashCode() : 0);
       result = 31 * result + getEmail().hashCode();
       return result;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Here is my repository interface

   ```
   @Repository
   public interface EmployeeRepository extends 
            ReactiveMongoRepository<Employee, UUID> {

        }
   ```

3.Here is my handler

```
@Component
public class EmployeeHandler {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    public Mono<ServerResponse> createNewEmployee(ServerRequest request) {
        Mono<Employee> employeeMono = request.bodyToMono(Employee.class);
        Mono<Employee> newEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employeeMono);
        return ServerResponse.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .build(newEmployee);
    }
}
```

Compile error I am seeing at line "Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'com.kj.webfluxcruddemo.entity.Employee'"

```
Mono<Employee> newEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employeeMono);
```

Comment: thanks @Stephen Nicoll, thats solve the problem.